# Can you find the cipher that I used?

Tags: cipher

I have encoded a phrase, using a cipher that I invented. But I don't want you to decode it, rather I want you to figure out how my cipher works.

This is the phrase that I encrypted

> Find the connection between this phrase and the output. You don't even have to do any solving, just figure out how this was encrypted

This is the key that I used

> A Blemished Orange

This is the encrypted phrase

> 1YaF7\B*,IdM#mI7\$iEB8lbnOKl5o.f9,J+772V2??16;XV2[)nhOov4elOT@h?Iw7nAO-2Nt2*,Sdq7XW&lBW0%^>u-C>,0)XSV&(627K,lHw7XeL8\B$PSj@[7n?PBbYbm@

These are important, but you'll have to figure out how

> 20
>
> 9100, 9129
>
> Python

That's everything, see what you can find!

Comment: That's much better, nice job! +1.